# Why is the print statement encountered five times in the following program?

Tags: c, recursion, logic

According to the logic of recursion, the `printf()` at the end must be encountered only once. The `main()` after `if()` should send the control back to the beginning. Only after `var` becomes zero should we reach the `printf()`. Why do we encounter the `printf()` five times? I know that this has been asked before but this logic is not explained in there.

```
void main()
{
    static int var=5;
    if(--var){
      main();
    }
    printf("%d\n", var);
}
```

Comment: Hint: Where does each recursive call *finish* ?

Comment: Calling `main()` is UB.

Comment: A method call is not a jmp, it will return to where you called it after completion.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` statement is not within the `if`. Each (recursive) call to `main` will ultimately call `printf` before terminating.

Answer (score 1):

*"the `printf()` at the end must be encountered only once"* that's incorrect.

you enter `main()` five times, so you will exit it 5 times. Each invocation of `main()` enters a new *copy* of it, opening a new stack frame for it.

When the next invocation has printed its value and exited, the control returns to the previous invocation, at the point after the recursive call.

Answer (score -2):

You should read the logic of recursion again i guess..

When the function is called from inside that function only, that presently executing function and all its parameters are pushed into the stack, and the newly called function starts executing. As this function calls gets over, the execution returns to the previous function (by popping it from the stack), and it will start executing from the point where it left..

Now, you can trace your program and check with his logic..